Valores que se borran de un array de Checkbox en un stepper
Poseo un stepper en Angular usando primeng.
Los valores de un step se borran cuando voy al paso anterior o al paso posterior y estoy pudiendo volver a restablecerlos.
Este es mi código HTML.
`   <div *ngSwitchCase="3">
      <form [formGroup]="serviciosForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Seleccione Servicios:</label>
          <div *ngFor="let servicio of listaServicios">        
            <p-checkbox 
              [value]="servicio.id" 
              [label]="servicio.nombre"
              formArrayName ="selectedServices"
              (onChange)="onCheckboxChange($event, servicio)">
            </p-checkbox>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" pButton label="Anterior" (click)="anteriorStep()"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton label="Siguiente" (click)="siguienteStep()"></button>
      </form>
    </div>`

Y en Angular:
export class TurnoComponent implements OnInit {
`    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private turnoService: TurnoService,
        private serviciosService: ServiciosService,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
       private stateService: ServicioEstadoStepperTurnoService
        .
        .
        .
         ) {
          this.serviciosService.getServicios().subscribe(res => {
           this.listaServicios = res as Servicio[];
           this.addCheckboxes();
         });
    
         this.stateService.servicios$.subscribe(servicios => {
           if (servicios.length > 0) {
           this.updateSelectedServices(servicios);
           }
         });

      ngOnInit() {
      this.serviciosForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedServices: this.fb.array([]),
       });
        }
     private addCheckboxes() {
        this.listaServicios.forEach(() => {
        const control = new FormControl(false); // Añadimos un control por cada checkbox
        this.selectedServices.push(control);
      });
     }
     guardarValoresActuales() { 
        this.stateService.setServicios(
        this.selectedServices.value.map((selected, i) => 
          ({ id: this.listaServicios[i].id, value: selected })
      ));
   
      }
      onCheckboxChange(e: any, servicio: any) {
    const selectedServices = this.selectedServices;
    
    if (e.checked) {
      selectedServices.push(new FormControl(servicio.id));
    } else {
      const index = selectedServices.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === servicio.id);
      selectedServices.removeAt(index);
    }

    this.guardarValoresActuales();
  }

 updateSelectedServices(servicios: { id: number, value: boolean }[]) {
    servicios.forEach((servicio, i) => {
      console.log('updateSelectedServices', servicios);
      if (servicio.value) {
        this.selectedServices.at(i).setValue(true);
      }
    });
  }
 siguienteStep() {
    this.activeIndex++;
    this.guardarValoresActuales();     
    if (this.activeIndex === 3) this.restoreState();
  }
 anteriorStep() {
    this.activeIndex--;
    this.guardarValoresActuales();
    if (this.activeIndex === 3) this.restoreState();
 
  }
 private restoreState() {
    const servicios = this.stateService.getServicios();
    if (servicios.length > 0) {
      servicios.forEach((servicio, index) => {
        this.selectedServices.at(index).setValue(servicio.value);
      });
    }
  }`


Y este es el servicio que mantiene el estado del stepper
export class ServicioEstadoStepperTurnoService {
 <kbd> private serviciosSource = new BehaviorSubject<{ id: number, value: boolean }[]>([]);
  servicios$ = this.serviciosSource.asObservable();

  setServicios(servicios: { id: number, value: boolean }[]) {
    this.serviciosSource.next(servicios);
  }

  getServicios() {
    return this.serviciosSource.getValue();
  }
}
</kbd>

Actualmente los checkbox tildatos se visualizan destildados al volver.
Necesito que los valores tildados en el checkbox, cuando se retorne al stepper = 3 se vuelvan a setear y se vean tildadas las elecciones previas..

En Angular 16 lo que hice fue crear una signal del tipo de dato de lo que iba a guardar (una reservacion) y en cada paso del stepper escribía los datos en la señal, así se mantenía al cambiar entre pasos mientras que permitía que al regresar pudiera elegir otra opción sin perder todos los datos.
